# How to render RowWidget after adding row in store dnamically

Tags: extjs

I want to re-render the `RowWidget` after dynamically adding a new data row in it's store. 
When I add a new row in store, RowWidget dones not show the newly added row. 
 
**Store:**

```
[
   {firstName: 'Peter',   lastName: 'Venkman'},
   {firstName: 'Egon',    lastName: 'Spengler'},
   {firstName: 'Ray',     lastName: 'Stantz'},
   {firstName: 'Winston', lastName: 'Zeddemore'}
]
```

**RowWidget**

```
{
    ptype: 'rowwidget',
    tooltip: 'View Contacts',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'grid',
        bind: {
            store: {
                data: '{record.contacts}',
            },
        },
        columns: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `record` under row it's should happen automatically.
Just add record to store into your rowwidget grid.

Look at my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/34tl&view/editor)